# Java count string occurrence and sort in reverse order

Tags: java, string, sorting, linkedhashmap

I was having some trouble when trying to count the string occurrence and sort them in descending order. Here is the list of sample inputs:

```
test, test, to, to, to, to, today, tomorrow, today
```

The desired output is in this order:

```
to, test, today tomorrow
```

Here is my code to count the string occurrence and sort them in reverse order:

```
Map<String, Integer> sortedTextSegmentList = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
 for (String s : textSegmentList) {
     if (sortedTextSegmentList.get(s) != null) {
         sortedTextSegmentList.put(s, sortedTextSegmentList.get(s) + 1);
     } else {
         sortedTextSegmentList.put(s, 1);
     }
 }

 sortedTextSegmentList.entrySet().stream()
         .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (x, y)-> {throw new AssertionError();}, LinkedHashMap::new
         ));
```

However, I am getting this output:

```
test, to, today, tomorrow
```

When I try to print out:

```
sortedTextSegmentList.forEach((key, value) -> {
         System.out.println("KEY" + key);
         System.out.println("VALUE  " + value);
 });
```

I am getting test 2, to 4, tomorrow 1, today 2 which the counter is correct. However, it just does not sort in descending order. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to look at using a `TreeMap` or a `SortedMap`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html

Comment: You're discarding the sorted map and printing the original...

Comment: @shmosel How to access the sorted map?

Comment: `sortedTextSegmentList = sortedTextSegmentList.entrySet().stream().sorted(...).collect(...);`

Comment: I see I see that worked well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your use of `LinkedHashMap` should cause the result to maintain its ordering, you never actually assign the result of your `collect` operation to `sortedTextSegmentList`. As a result, your `forEach` is iterating over the first map you created, which is not sorted the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have been looking at "sortedTextSegmentList" which has the occurences in the order you are seeing them i.e. "test, to, today, tomorrow"

Try below :

```
LinkedHashMap sortedMap = sortedTextSegmentList.entrySet().stream()
         .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (x, y)-> {throw new AssertionError();}, LinkedHashMap::new
         ));
```

sortedMap should have the data in the order you are looking for.